# horizontally (sideways) expanding menus using html and css in IE6

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-6

i had been trying to get horizontally expanding menu's coding to work.. the menu has an image background and it should expand sideways as the content increases.

in code, i use `background-position:left` for one div and `background-position:right` for the next inner div.

it works fine in all the browsers except IE6... as IE6 doesnt support `background-position:left`

i need the same to work in IE6 as well.. for instance the top menu [here](http://scentjunkies.com/).

do i need to code differently??

Comment: Could you use the non-standard background-position-x and background-position-y in a separate IE6_fix.css stylesheet file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be overdoing it... but according to netrenderer it works till ie 5.5

http://photoshopmesta.net/1/test.html

CSS:

```
.left { 
    width: 25px;
    height: 46px;
    background-image: url(http://scentjunkies.com/wp-content/themes/Scent%20Junkies/images/menur_hover_left.png);
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
}

.middle {
    height: 46px;
    background-image: url(http://scentjunkies.com/wp-content/themes/Scent%20Junkies/images/menur_hover_right.png);
    background-position: top left;
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    float: left;
}
.middle span {   
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #ffffff;
    padding: 19px 20px 10px 20px;
    float: left;
}

.right {
    width: 40px;
    height: 46px;
    background-image: url(http://scentjunkies.com/wp-content/themes/Scent%20Junkies/images/menur_hover_right.png);
    background-position: top right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span class="left"></span> 
<span class="middle"> 
    <span>Lorem ipsum</span> 
</span> 
<span class="right"></span>
```

Comment: no problem. I'd like to note that despite it working.. it really is quite crappy way of doing it as far as big radiuses go as you cant place text in those side areas.. easily.... :D ( meaning that the width of the radius determines the minimum padding on the sides... )

Comment: Indeed and even in this case where you have rather big radius.. if you dont use the padding i put on the sides of ".middle span" it'll look just fine..

Answer (score 0):

Try using the extended form:

```
#something{
    background-position: left center;
}
```

Ad@m

Answer (score 0):

Many people have issues trying to get code to work correctly in IE6. If you don't really need it I would recommend not trying as it is very difficult.

If you are going to go ahead with it I recommend creating a different version of the website that is compatible with IE6, using a different css file for IE6 only. See the link below.

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

Also this is very handy for dealing with IE6 quirks

http://www.virtuosimedia.com/dev/css/ultimate-ie6-cheatsheet-how-to-fix-25-internet-explorer-6-bugs

Comment: i guess i have seen the code for the same which works fine with all the browsers including ie6... but i find that snippet confusing...

Comment: @Amen149 As far as needing ie6 goes you can more or less check that here: http://www.ie6countdown.com/

Comment: @Lollero.. i too agree with your view.. i hate IE6.. but ppl in my concern are definitely fond of this and so is my senior...:(